# Running django on a server

Tags: django

Im trying to run a django project through docker-compose while working on a Ubuntu 18.04 linux server at myIP that I've connected to using putty.

I cant use the local host as this will run the project but I can't see it due to port forwarding.

When I try to use the IP and port for my space on the server ($ python manage.py runserver myIP:myport) it seems to default to 0.0.0.0:myport and gives me an error telling me that there is something already running on it. Im working on the server on myIP, how can I get django to use this server IP amd port?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can kill your port by running `sudo fuser -k <myport>/tcp`, and if you want to run on different port, see inside dockerfile if there is env variable for that, if no you can change dockerfile and make use of different port